# How to create year dropdown in Birthday when user is required to enter birthday

Tags: javascript

Please I'm creating a sign up page and needed to add birthday to it. So I used "select" to create the day and month but it becomes practically impossible to use "select" since years is usually much maybe from 1900s till present. please how can i use code to fix that problem? I mean how can i create a dropdown that users can pick their birth year from?

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: How about `<input type="date">` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. One way** to achieve this is using **input type *date***

You can use `<input type="date">`.

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

`<input>` elements of `type="date"` create input fields that let the user enter a date. You can also add a minimum and maximum date validation.

```html
<label for="birthday">Enter Birthday:</label>

<input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday" value="2021-11-14">
```

**2. The second way** to achieve these using libraries like:

- [react-datetime](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datetime)
- [react-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker)
- [react-datetime-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datetime-picker)